# Angularjs : How to repeat unknown number of div?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to build as many `div` as I have `$scope.fileContent` variables like below :

```
<div class="dd-nodrag" ng-nestable ng-model="fileContent">
    <div>
        {{$item.title}} {{$item.value}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dd-nodrag" ng-nestable ng-model="fileContent1">
    <div>
        {{$item.title}} {{$item.value}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dd-nodrag" ng-nestable ng-model="fileContent2">
    <div>
        {{$item.title}} {{$item.value}}
    </div>
</div> 


          ...

<div class="dd-nodrag" ng-nestable ng-model="fileContentN">
    <div>
        {{$item.title}} {{$item.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to only write something like this :

```
<div class="dd-nodrag" ng-nestable ng-model="fileContent">
    <div>
        {{$item.title}} {{$item.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and repeat this as many times as I have `$scope.fileContent`

This has no sense but what I want to do is :

```
for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
    <div class="dd-nodrag" ng-nestable ng-model="fileContent"+i>
        <div>
            {{$item.title}} {{$item.value}}
        </div>
    </div> 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just use ng-repeat:

```
<div class="dd-nodrag" ng-repeat="fileContent in fileContents">
    <div>
        {{fileContent.title}} {{fileContent.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, seems like you have independent variables (objects) in $scope like:

```
    $scope.fileContent = {}
    $scope.fileContent1 = {}
    $scope.fileContent2 = {}
    $scope.fileContent3 = {}
    .
    $scope.fileContentN = {}
```

If yes, you might want to encapsulate your independent variables (objects) in a javascript array (JSON) like:

```
    $scope.fileContents = [{ title: "T0", value: "V0" }, 
                           { title: "T1", value: "V1" }, 
                           { title: "T2", value: "V2" }];
```

You can loop through javascript arrays using ng-repeat in angularjs as jeremy suggested like:

```
    <div class="dd-nodrag" ng-repeat="fileContent in fileContents">
        <div>
            {{fileContent.title}} {{fileContent.value}}
        </div>
    </div>
```